# Resource Limit Exceeded- xgb.deploy

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

When I tried to deploy example from Amazon SageMaker

```
xgb_predictor = xgb.deploy(initial_instance_count=1,
                           instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge')
```

ResourceLimitExceeded: An error occurred (ResourceLimitExceeded) when calling the CreateEndpoint operation: The account-level service limit 'ml.m4.xlarge for endpoint usage' is 0 Instances, with current utilization of 0 Instances and a request delta of 1 Instances. Please contact AWS support to request an increase for this limit.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Your AWS account does not have access to launch ml.* instances. You would need to create ticket with AWS support to request for limit increase.

Comment: The error is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS is using soft limits to prevent customers from making a mistake that might cause them more money than they expected. When you are starting to use a new service, such as Amazon SageMaker, you will hit these soft limits and you need to ask specifically to raise them using the "Support" link on the top right side of your AWS management console.

Here is a link to guide on how to do that: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/manage-service-limits/

You will usually get the limit increased within a couple of days. In the meanwhile, you can choose a smaller instance (such as t2) that are often available.

Comment: Can someone share an explanation for common sagemaker workflows, particularly persisting notebooks for a long time?  Unlike EMR, it looks like stopped notebooks still count against total notebook limit.

Comment: is there a way that I can reduce the number of instances I currently have?

Comment: @JonathanIshii, I'm not sure what do you mean. Simply choose fewer instances.

Answer (score 0):

What @Guy answered is correct, if you want to deploy then you need to request a limit incrase for the specific instance type,

Steps to Request Limit Increase for ml.m4.xlarge

1. visit aws console https://console.aws.amazon.com/
2. click on support on the top right corner
3. click create a case (orange button)
4. select Service Limit Increase radio button
5. For Limit Type, Search and Select SageMaker Notebook Instances
6. select the same region as the region that is displayed on the top right corner of your amazon console.
7. Write a short Use case description
8. For Limit, Select ml.[x].[x] (in your case, ml.m4.xlarge)
9. New Limit Values 1

It may take 48 hours for this manual support ticket to turn around.